# Pythonic way to find common elements in list of lists that show at least in two sub lists

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following list of lists

```py
p=[ [1,2,3],
    [1,9,9],
    [7,2,3]
    [1,2,4]
```

1 for example appears in sub lists 0, 1 and 3.
2 appears in sub lists 0, 2 and 3.
On the other hand, 4, 9 and 7 appear only in one list each.

Therefore, the expected result should be

```py
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: to find common elements in a list of lists that show at least in two sub lists

Comment: What did you try? Please fix the code you have posted - it is not a valid python code.

Answer (score 3):

Create a "flattened" set of elements and use a list comprehension to keep only elements that exist in more than one sub-list:

```
elements = set(item for sublist in p for item in sublist)
>>> [e for e in elements if sum((e in sublist) for sublist in p)>1]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Counter class (from collections) to count elements found in each sub-list. In order to properly count elements (like 9) that appear multiple times in the same list, you also need to convert the lists into sets to that only one instance of these repeated elements is counted per list.

With the help of chain (from itertools) you can do it all in one list comprehension:

```
p=[ [1,2,3],
    [1,9,9],
    [7,2,3],
    [1,2,4] ]

from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

r = [e for ec in [Counter(chain(*map(set,p)))] for e,c in ec.items() if c>1]

print(r) # [1, 2, 3]
```

Or, in a bit more legible form :

```
counts = Counter(chain(*map(set,p)))
result = [element for element,count in counts.items() if count>1]
```